# How to format and re-use a locked down thumb drive?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I recently went to an IT conference where the company Veeam was giving away free plastic cards that had a detachable thumb drive.  When I plugged the thumb drive into my Windows 7 computer, Windows discovered it and installed the drivers it needed, and then it autoran a utility that launched "Start / Run" and typed in a web address to their site.

Since this is technically some type of "device" that Windows sees, and it has "data" on it, I'd like to be able to format and re-use it; but Windows doesn't see it as a "disk" or "drive".

What can I do to gain access to this thing and blow it away so I can re-use it?

Edit:  So I used USBDeview tool to look at the device and it's classified as a USB Input Device, and the vendor ID is 05ac, which supposedly indicates that it's a digital camera by Apple, Inc - WTH? O_o....  Maybe it's not possible to convert it to a storage device because it doesn't have the capability?...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unusable "Geek Squad" Flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/203791/unusable-geek-squad-flash-drive)

Comment: *"it autoran a utility that launched "Start / Run" and typed in a web address to their site"* That's some shady stuff there.  Why wouldn't they just launch the site outright?

Comment: @Brad because there is no way to do that via a flash drive.

Comment: techie007: Thanks for the link, but it didn't help.  The info was not relevant - My "device" does not show up in Windows Explorer or in Disk Management.

Comment: It sounds like this is mimicking a keyboard rather than a flash drive, I suspect there is no actual flash memory on it to format. Multimedia keyboards have a "browser" key and time it sounds like you have a new keyboard that only knows how to type the address of a particular website.